# What new technology is in Firefox Quantum and (possibly) not other browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, microsoft-edge, firefox-quantum

So I've been seeing a lot of buzz lately around Firefox Quantum and claims on it's major performance improvements on previous versions as well as verses the competition.

I am interested to know the technological differences, I can recall talks of using Rust in the past and on googling seems like they have, I also came across one of their blog posts https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/11/entering-the-quantum-era-how-firefox-got-fast-again-and-where-its-going-to-get-faster/.

It seems parallel computing is the main (only?) difference but I could be wrong so I jsut wanted to ask the community.